# Consulta MYSQL con rango de Fechas de un id

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta en mysql, la cual debe hacer que basado en un id dado y un rango de fechas, me traiga los registros que hay entre esas fechas. Estoy empezando a aprender mysql entonces lo mas seguro es que estoy formulando todo mal.

Esto lo estoy implemetando en un programita C#.
Esa parte ya esta y todo funciona, lo unico es que no se como realizar la consula, se me ocurrio tambien solo realizar la consulta del id y mediante 
c# filtrar las fechas del DateTimePicker, pero no creo que sea optimo si puedo directamente esto en la consulta mysql.

e intentado esto pero no funciona:

```
select * from registro_ausentismos where id = '381' 
AND (fecha_inicio between >= '2018-09-10'
AND fecha_final between <= '2018-09-30')
```

**Mas Info:**

Creo que con la siguiente imagen me hago entender un poco mas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay vemos que lo que hago es pedir un codigo de empleado y un rango de fechas, necesito que muestre los registros que hay entre las fechas seleccionadas, no se si se pueda hacer ese filtro directamente desde una consula MySQL.

```
    CREATE TABLE `registro_ausentismos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `apellidos` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `tipo_documento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `numero_documento` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `eps` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `cda` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `cargo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `numero_incapacidad` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tipo_evento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `dias_incapacidad` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fecha_inicio` DATE NOT NULL,
    `fecha_final` DATE NOT NULL,
    `codigo_diagnostico` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valor_incapacidad` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`numero_incapacidad`, `id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=45656656
;
```

y esa es la tabla donde se estan guardando los registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.
Si lo estás intentando en C#...podrías mostrar tu código? Por otro lado, no está muy claro lo que intentas. Que columnas quieres usar? `fecha_inicio`?`fecha_final`?

Comment: Podrias aclarar algo? between se usa en los casos en los que un campo, este entre dos valores. si tenes fecha_inicio y fecha_final, entonces no queres algo between un solo campo, si no que queres comparar las fechas con cada campo no? si quitas el between de tu consulta ya anda.

Comment: E actualiazdo con un poco mas de informacion. Gracias

Comment: Has aclarado un poco mas, efectivamente, pero por un lado, sigues sin poner el código C#. Si solo te interesa la consulta, deberías quitar la etiqueta C#. Por otro, como ya te dije antes, tienes dos campos de fecha. Por cual de ellos quieres filtrar?

Comment: @Pikoh no quiero comparar, quiero saber cuales registros hay entre esas dos fechas, por ejemplo: desde la fecha "2018-01-01" hasta "2018-08-30", el usuario "381" cuantos registros tiene.

Comment: Claro Andres, entiendo. El problema es...desde la fecha "2018-01-01" hasta "2018-08-30"... en que columna? En fecha_inicio? En fecha_final? En ambas? Si es en ambas...que las dos estén comprendidas en ese periodo?

Comment: Si señor la fecha inicio es una columna aparte de la final. Puede ser que tenga mal diseñada la tabla? o podria manejarse de esa manera; en columnas separadas?

Comment: La tabla puede estar bien o mal, solo dependiendo de tus especificaciones. Al filtrar, te interesa que aparezcan los registros en los que la fecha de baja se produjo en el periodo especificado? o te interesa que salgan los que fue la fecha de alta? Has pensado darle esa opción al usuario?

Comment: Todo lo que dijiste, esta bien y ayuda... fijate que ya te dije, que si sacas el between tu consulta ya funciona. Las tablas no parecen estar mal diseñadas, pero no se puede decir si una DB esta bien o mal, sin saber las reglas de negocios

Comment: @gbianchi Perdona, no lei bien tu comentario, y tienes razon si funciona si le quito el BETWEEN. XD, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tenecuidado porque larespuesta q aceptaste no es igual a la queplanteas en tu pregunta. Esa respuesta trae mas registros porque busca en intervalos diferentes

Comment: Entonces la desmarco o que hago? Porque ua encontre la solucion al problema @gbianchi

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, esta bien que la marques. Si la respuesta no contesta la pregunta, no deberia estar marcada porque futuros usuarios podrian confundirse (todos los comentarios deberian borrarse). Tambien se puede mejorar la respuesta para que sea correcta. La respuesta esa funciona, por mas que la query no sea como la pediste?

Comment: Si funciona, osea la query que yo tenia era una que se me ocurrio de momento, pero cabia la posibilidad de que alguien me proporcionara una mejor y mas completa.

Comment: Yo preguntaría una cosa: ¿por qué tienes una columna para marcar la fecha de inicio y otra para marcar la fecha final? ¿Acaso cada dato que registras (cada fila) usa ambas columnas? Si es sí: ¿no hay redundancia de datos? Si es no: ¿Entonces estamos hablando de intervalos de fechas? No sé, pero puede que estemos ante un error de diseño del modelo de datos. Tendrías que dar más detalles para saberlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en tu consulta, debería ser así;

```
SELECT * FROM registro_ausentismos 
WHERE id = '381' 
AND fecha_inicio BETWEEN '2018-09-10' AND '2018-09-30'
AND fecha_final BETWEEN '2018-09-10' AND '2018-09-30'
```

Te explico;

Cuando haces consultas entre rango de fechas utilizando `BETWEEN` solo debes decirle las 2 fechas separadas por `AND` sin ningún operador, ya que `BETWEEN` se encarga de todo.

Comment: Aunque lo que dices es cierto, creo que la pregunta no es lo suficientemente clara para obtener respuesta. Está usando en su consulta dos columnas, `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_final`. Tu respuesta solo usa uno, lo que deja claro que el OP debería aclarar mas su duda antes de responderle.

Comment: @Pikoh me he percatado de ello, mi intención es de primera mano hacerle saber que la consulta esta mal estructurada.

Comment: Si, te entiendo,el error de sintaxis era evidente. Pero tal vez en estos casos es mejor hacerle un comentario hasta que realmente aclare que es exactamente lo que quiere :)

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo Funciona! anque voy a investigar mejor como funciona el BETWEEN, porque usando mi consulta sin el BETWEEN tambien me trae los mismo datos. Muchas gracias!.

Comment: @AndresRodriguezFARP si tambien funciona con los peradores `>=` y `<=' pero estos los usas sin el `BETWEEN`

Comment: osea que hacen lo mismo?, o el BETWEEN es mas "Optimo"?

Comment: Esta respuesta noes incorrecta.pero no  trae los mismos datos q la que se plantea en la pregunta

Comment: Opino que si, aunque no he leído nada que me lo confirme, de todos modos la la sintaxis inclusive es mas limpia.

Comment: Como informacion, todo between es transformado por el motor de base de datos a campo >= and campo <=.  lo hace solo el motor.. No hay diferencia entre usar ninguno de los dos... pero tene en cuenta que este query no hace fecha_ini > dato and fecha_fin < dato. Hace fecha_ini > dato_ini and fecha_ini < dato_fin and fecha_fin > dato_ini and fecha_fin < dato_fin